# Definition of Negative Half Derivative

Tags: derivatives, integral-equations, fractional-calculus

I know the definition of positive fractional derivative, which is given by $$D^{\alpha} f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \frac{d}{d x} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^{\alpha}} dt,\quad\quad \alpha\in(0,1)$$

But I encounter the negative half derivative $D^{-1/2}$ , which I am quite confused with.

My professor assigned a problem which let us solve the integral equation $$ D^{-1 / 2} h(t)=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(t-s)}} h(s) \mathrm{d} s=g(t),$$ where $g$ is a nice function with $g(0)=0.$ And he gave a hint that lets us square $D^{-1/2}.$

I feel like the first equality is the definition of $D^{-1/2}$ but I am not sure. If it indeed is the definition of $D^{-1/2}$, can someone tell me the definition of $D^{-\beta}$ for any $\beta \gt0\,?$

Furthermore, can someone give me a further hint about the problem he assigned?

**My attempt:** Squaring $D^{-1/2}$, we get $$h^{-1}(t)=\int_0^t h(s)\mathrm{d}s=D^{-1/2}g(t)=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(t-s)}} g(s) \mathrm{d} s\,.$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t  $t$ and applying the Leibniz Integral Rule( but ${1\over \sqrt{t-t}}g(t) =\infty$, and it is invalided to use the Leibniz Integral Rule), we get $$h(t)=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^t\frac{1}{(t-s)^{\frac{3}{2}}}g(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

I think it may not be simplified further, but I am not sure. Could the integral in the right-hand-side be calculated further?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused - granted, I'm a novice to this sort of thing so maybe it's a dumb question. But shouldn't you be getting $D^{-1}$ (i.e. the antiderivative, not the derivative $h'$) when you, to use your phrasing, "square both sides"? Since it would amount to doing $D^{-1/2}$ again on each side and one of the properties we want to preserve from ordinary derivatives is $D^\alpha \circ D^\beta = D^{\alpha+\beta}$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Oh yea, you are right. I think it should be $D^{-1}$. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Also, regarding your question about whether this is the definition of the negative-half derivative, from what I could look up, there's a definition [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1626-12.pdf) you might find useful. Definition $1.2$ gives us, for a antiderivative of order $\lambda$ (derivative of order $-\lambda$),

$$D^{-\lambda} f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\lambda)}\int_0^x \frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^{1-\lambda}} ds$$

Comment: Take $\lambda = 1/2$ and recall $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt \pi$ and you'll get the expression you want. Granted this is not the definition I'm familiar with for fractional derivatives and don't see immediately why it might be equivalent to the one you mentioned (i.e. the one I'm familiar with), but I guess you could  take it as **a** definition of it regardless.

Comment: *(Minor footnote: corrected some typos/made clarifications in the previous two comments that I accidentally looked over).*

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thank you for the definition you introduced, though I don’t see the connection between the two definitions too.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Hey Eevee, I found the reason why they define $D^{-\lambda}$ in this way. Defining it in this way is to promise that we have $D^{-\lambda_2}D^{-\lambda_1}=D^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_1)}.$ You can see the "Heuristics" part on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus . The operator $J^{\alpha}$ on that page is the same as our operator $D^{-\alpha}$, and there is a proof for the property I mentioned above.

Comment: Huh, neat. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets use the notation $\ds{\hat{\mrm{f}}\pars{u} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{t}\expo{-ut}\dd t}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-ut}\int_{0}^{t}{\mrm{h}\pars{s} \over \root{\pi\pars{t - s}}}\dd s\,\dd t & = \hat{\mrm{g}}\pars{u}
\\[5mm]
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{h}\pars{s}
\int_{s}^{\infty}{\expo{-ut} \over \root{t - s}}\dd t\,\dd s & = \hat{\mrm{g}}\pars{u}
\\[5mm]
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{h}\pars{s}\expo{-us}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-1/2}\expo{-ut}\dd t}
_{\ds{=\ \root{\pi}u^{-1/2}}}\
\,\dd s & = \hat{\mrm{g}}\pars{u}
\\[5mm]
\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1/2}\,\mrm{h}\pars{s}\expo{-us}\
\,\dd s & = \hat{\mrm{g}}\pars{u}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
u^{-1/2}\,\mrm{h}\pars{s} & = \int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}
\hat{\mrm{g}}\pars{u}\expo{su}
{\dd u \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}
$$
\implies \bbx{\mrm{h}\pars{s} =
\root{u}\int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}
\hat{\mrm{g}}\pars{u}\expo{su}
{\dd u \over 2\pi\ic}}
$$

Comment: I can follow your proof now. Thank you!

Comment: Nice. Thanks.${}{}{}$